# How can I write a MySQL query that will only return duplicate values, WITHOUT using aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql, restriction

I have a very basic table that consists of worker names and manager names:

```
CREATE TABLE Work (
Worker_name varchar(50) NOT NULL 
Manager_name varchar(50) NOT NULL;
```

This table allows a worker to be his own manager, a manager to be in charge of multiple workers, etc.

I'm supposed to write a query that will show every manager who manages at least 2 different employees, BUT I can't use aggregate commands or GROUP BY.

If somebody could give me a hint that would be great. I like figuring things out but this has really got me stumped.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: you can create 2 tables and use rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is a little tedious, but it should do what you need it to do, or at least get you on the right track :)

```
SELECT w1.* FROM Work w1
    INNER JOIN Work w2 ON w2.Manager_name = w1.Manager_name AND w2.Worker_name != w1.Worker_name
    INNER JOIN Work w3 ON w3.Manager_name = w1.Manager_name AND w3.Worker_name != w2.Worker_name
    WHERE w1.Manager_name = w1.Worker_name
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up only self-joining once, but it seems to be working. Do you mind if I ask how you thought of this? Something about self-joining is very un-intuitive to me. In all other joins I have done, I directly select the criteria I want, not "avoid" it like I did in this query.

Comment: You're welcome! I do a lot of analytical queries at work, and there are many times when I have to join on transaction data to determine sequential events, and that process includes joining the transaction table onto itself, grabbing the next sequential event that was not the same as the current event. It just happened to be something I've had to do before, and the symptoms of your query seemed to match :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the sql below, it works well in mysql, hopes help

SELECT distinct Manager_name from Work a where a.Manager_name in 
(select Manager_name from Work b where a.Worker_name != b.Worker_name);